# YTD Calculation in Google big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a requirement to calculate YTD ,For example
current date is Oct 12 2022 then I need to get all the data from Ist day of the month (Oct 1st 2022 till current date) not Oct 12 .
I have the query which gets the data from Current_date to Previous year Oct 12 2022.
How do i get the data from 1st day of the month for the preivous year oct 1st to current_date

Below query works perfect for current_Date to previous year same date

```
Select * from table 
 WHERE CAST(DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(SAFE_CAST(snapshot_timestamp AS INT64))) AS DATE )  BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the first date of a month,  truncate  the date to the month:
`date_trunc(CURRENT_DATE(),month)`.

```sql
WITH
  tbl AS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE("2021-01-01"),DATE("2023-01-01"),INTERVAL 1 day)) AS snapshot_date)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  snapshot_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB( date_trunc(CURRENT_DATE(),month), INTERVAL 12 month) and date_trunc(CURRENT_DATE(),month)
  order by 1
```